# How to convert a tuple to string?

Tags: python, string, tuples

How can you convert a tuple into a string in the most simplest way possible? for instance. Lets say I have a list of pairs such as:

```
[(1,"hi"),(True,False),(3,4)]
```

and I want to convert the first pair to '1hi'

Comment: What have you tried? What would you like for the last tuple - "34"? For the second tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
>>> l = [(1,"hi"),(True,False),(3,4)]
>>> for i in l:
...     print str(i[0])+str(i[1])
```

Comment: `for first, second in l: print str(first) + str(second)`

Answer (score 2):

For the first element only:

```
l =  [(1,"hi"),(True,False),(3,4)]
s = "".join(str(x) for x in l[0])
print s
```

To do this to all elements:

```
for t in l:
    s = "".join(str(x) for x in t)
    print s
```

Gives:

```
1hi
TrueFalse
34
```

Answer (score 2):

```
map(lambda e: ''.join(map(str,e)), 
        [(1,"hi"),(True,False),(3,4)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> l = [(1,"hi"),(True,False),(3,4)]
>>> ''.join(map(str, l[0]))
'1hi'
>>> ''.join(map(str, l[1]))
'TrueFalse'
>>> ''.join(map(str, l[2]))
'34'
```

Comment: How is this different from @perreal's answer?

Comment: @kojiro, This uses `map` instead of generator expression.